# GCC ARM Os Template function optimization

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, embedded, compiler-optimization

```
class GpioF7xx : public Gpio {
public:
    template <uint32_t PIN>
    static GpioF7xx create(GPIO_TypeDef* base) {
        static_assert(PIN >= 0 && PIN =< 15, "Gpio pins are only available from 0 to 15");

        return GpioF7xx(base, PIN);
    }
```

I have a pretty simple Gpio class which abstracts register allocation.
In this class I have the pin argument at compile time, so why not check if the pin is a valid one with `static_assert`.

I assume it is easier to get a compiler warning, then being stuck in some handler.

```
 .text._ZN8GpioF7xx6createILm6EEES_P12GPIO_TypeDef
            0x0000000008000a84       0x1c cmake-build-debug/main.o
            0x0000000008000a84                GpioF7xx GpioF7xx::create<6ul>(GPIO_TypeDef*)
 .text._ZN8GpioF7xx6createILm7EEES_P12GPIO_TypeDef
            0x0000000008000aa0       0x1c cmake-build-debug/main.o
            0x0000000008000aa0                GpioF7xx GpioF7xx::create<7ul>(GPIO_TypeDef*)
 ...
```

Using (-O0) gcc-none-eabi toolchain the linker generated the linker map above (So far so good).

Using -Os the linker file doesn't contain the symbols anymore.

My Question: How far can this be optimized ? Does anyone know where I can find documentation about this. Because then I would directly put the template at the GpioF7xx class.

I actually created a static factory method as I didn't wanted a separate class for each pin in my binary.

Furthermore: I appreciate any comment how this could be more idiomatic as I'm coming from web. And don't have professional embedded / Cpp experience.

Comment: Are you using this class anywhere ? I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler removes unused type when you optimize for size.

Comment: should be: `static_assert(PIN >= 0 && PIN < 16, "Gpio pins are only available from 0 to 15");`

Comment: `How far can this be optimized ?` what should be optimized? Code speed? Code size? What are you trying to achieve? For me this looks like premature optimization.

Comment: `I actually created a static factory method as I didn't wanted a separate class for each pin in my binary.`
You don't need that in C++. Factory methods are needed in object oriented programming languages because everything has to be part of a class or an object. 
In C++ you can just use a function.

However for the rest it's rather difficult to help you because it's not clear on what you are trying to do here. Looks like premature optimization in my eyes.

Comment: The "Os" (minimize size) optimizer is doing what it's supposed to be doing, stripping out unnecessary symbols, removing non-functional code to keep the binary size low. It's optimized away the entire factory overhead, so there's literally nothing further to do. I find your template an acceptably idiomatic way to validate pins at compile-time, so 

Comment: @Clonk Yes, I have 4 Gpios with connected LEDs. Which are also working afterwards

@MarekR Its probably preoptimization with a mix of not knowing c++ good enough.
My Main point is that I want an error at compile time. So from my current point of view I have two choices.

1: Using an enum. Then I would do something like `GpioF7xx(GPIOC, GpioF7xx::PIN_6)` Therefore it would be impossible to use an invalid PIN.

But in other cases that is not possible.

Comment: (Example of what woudn't work):
I also have a Timer class with a method `into_pwm(uint32_t channel, uint32_t duty_cycle)`. Which extends an interface of `Timer::into_pwm(...)` 

If I would use an `enum Channel` instead of uint32_t, i couldn't override the `TimerF7xx::into_pwm(Channel)` as it would require a Timer::Channel (Base) instead of TimerF7xx::Channel (Derived).

Little bit hard to explain without submitting all the code

Comment: But what I would need in the derived class is the MCU specific channel configurations. 
(Timer Base = Interface) + (Timer derived = MCU specific implementation)